# SPARC register names to binary

Tags: cpu-registers, sparc

So in SPARC V8, the destination register (rd) occupies 5 bits of the instruction (25th-29th). My question is: is there a document with map associating each register name, say %i1, to its respective 5-bit binary, say, 01010? I can't find such thing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register numbers 0-7 are %g0-%g7, 8-15 are %o0-%o7, 16-23 are %l0-%l7 and 24-31 are %i0-%i7

Answer (score 0):

http://www.gaisler.com/doc/sparcv8.pdf

Note that Sparc uses register windows.... so you are addressing the register window not the register file itself.

The data formats are defined on page 18 of the Sparc V8 manual. Sparc uses LSB 0 bit notation. The order of the register window locations names are on page 24.

A byte for instance is 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 with 0 being least significant.

This in turn means the instructions map as follows.

```
0   00000   %g0
1   00001   %g1
2   00010   %g2
3   00011   %g3
4   00100   %g4
5   00101   %g5
6   00110   %g6
7   00111   %g7
8   01000   %o0
9   01001   %o1
10  01010   %o2
11  01011   %o3
12  01100   %o4
13  01101   %o5
14  01110   %o6
15  01111   %o7
16  10000   %l0
17  10001   %l1
18  10010   %l2
19  10011   %l3
20  10100   %l4
21  10101   %l5
22  10110   %l6
23  10111   %l7
24  11000   %i0
25  11001   %i1
26  11010   %i2
27  11011   %i3
28  11100   %i4
29  11101   %i5
30  11110   %i6
31  11111   %i7
```